# What sizes are the images available through the /sites endpoint?

Tags: support, api-v2

I see `logo_url`, `icon_url`, `favicon_url`, `high_resolution_icon_url`... But I wasn't able to find any information about any of those images in the documentation.  Are any of them fixed size?  And/or is there a place where I can find the intent for each of those images?

Answer (score 1):

> "Are any of the fixed size?"

I can't really answer that question directly, but for reference, the dimensions of the images supplied by the API for Stack Overflow are as follows:

```
Image:                    Dimensions:
=====================================
logo_url                  250x61
icon_url                  158x158
favicon_url               16x16
high_resolution_icon_url  316x316
```

I didn't have the patience to verify if the other sites used the same dimensions - but I would assume that they do.

> "And/or is there a place where I can find the intent for each of those images?"

There is nothing in the documentation (that I am aware of) indicating specific intents for these images. But here is my humble opinion on each of the images:

- `logo_url` - this image contains not only the site logo but also the name of the site in the appropriate font. I can't really see a valid use for this that wouldn't violate the [trademark guidelines](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance), however - but you never know.
- `icon_url` - the primary purpose of this image (judging from the filename) is to serve as an [`apple-touch-icon`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) - an image that will be used by iOS devices when a page is bookmarked. Of course, there are a lot of other things such an image could be used for.
- `favicon_url` - this image is provided in `.ico` format so I can't really see much use for it.
- `high_resolution_icon_url` - basically the same as `icon_url` but a much higher resolution. This might be valuable on high resolution displays or an area of your site that requires a *really* large copy of the logo.

Comment: A few corrections.  `logo_url` is whatever size the site's actual logo is, and can change as sites get new designs.  `favicon_url` is an .ico, and can technically hold multiple resolutions, but 16x16 is guaranteed for favicons.  Our trademark guidelines only restrict using the logo in advertising, you can use it to identify sections/modes/content/etc. in your app without issue.